# How to detect data types from string?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, abstract-data-type, custom-data-type

There is a pseudocode:

```
s = input()

if s == 'int':
    func<int>(...)
if s == 'char':
    func<char>(...)
and there're more if blocks
```

How can I write code that can do this without any `if`. Like code below:

```
s = input()
func<s>(...) #auto detect type in s
```

I need a solution in C++.

Comment: What you're asking isn't really possible. You can *encode* what type something isn't into the type itself, but computers aren't magic.

Comment: Sure he can. By using the factory pattern, he can accept a string, which returns an an object that uses a common interface shared by the class template. In this instance, it might not even need that, since it seems it only calls a function, and the actual template type can be handled by the factory.

Comment: @swalog But that doesn't remove the if, it just moves it elsewhere...

Comment: If course @Alegnem, but I assume that this is still in the spirit of what OP has in mind.

Comment: @swalog Possibly. Also a map with string -> function mapping can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not directly possible with templated functions, I recommend a table lookup of `std::string` vs. function pointer.

For example:

```
typedef void (*Function_Pointer_Type)(void);  
struct Table_Entry
{
  char const * data_type_name;
  Function_Pointer_Type data_type_function;
};

void Process_Int(void);
void Process_Double(void);

static const Table_Entry data_type_function_table[] =
{
  {"int", Process_Int},
  {"double", Process_Double},
};
static const unsigned int number_of_data_types =
  sizeof(data_type_function_table) / sizeof(data_type_function_table[0]);

// ...
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_data_types; ++i)
{
  if (s == data_type_function_table[i].data_type_name)
  {
    data_type_function_table.data_type_function();
    break;
  }
}
```

Another method is to use `std::map<std::string, Function_Pointer_Type>`.  The map must be initialized before it is used.  The static, constant table doesn't need to be initialized at runtime.

Comment: Not sure why you bother with the manual loop; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8183e4b7f6d79f0 -- or, using an `unordered_map`, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95df7e4dcdee9adc

Comment: I think it's not a good idea, if I've created 100000 types(in some big project), how to build this table?

Comment: @dyp:  Because my company hasn't upgraded the compilers to use C++11 and all my Visual Studio compilers are C++03.  It's a habit and to me, more readable.  I don't see any advantage to `auto` except typing and I can type fast.

Comment: And it's dangerous, it's impossible to build this table without any mistake when the number of types is large.

Comment: @TioPlato:  For 100000 types, you will need to write a program that creates the table.  Or *something smells like your design is flawed.*

Comment: @TioPlato:  With 100000 types, and your template style, you are bound to inject defects, *purely from typing*.  So give up the requirement to type it in perfectly the first time.